# Unity OnPointerUp

Tags: user-interface, events

Why doesn’t this MonoBehaviour method get fired?

I have this code, which is copied straight from the scripting documentation:

```
public class SwishButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(Time.time+" OnPointerUp");
    }
}
```

It gets attached to a button. The setup is that the button is on a panel which is normally not active. As soon as the mouse button goes down the panel is set active, so the button is enabled, but then releasing the mouse button does not trigger the method. If the panel is active when the editor starts then it works as it should.

I also tried subclassing Button with the above override. No luck

Why would event handling be subject to the enclosing panel’s status?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue in that `OnPointerUp` didn't fire with code similar to yours - I then added the complimentary `IPointerDownHandler` and `OnPointerDown` method and now `OnPointerUp` fires!

Obviously if you don't need `OnPointerDown` you can just leave it empty, but it seems like it *does* have to exist for `OnPointerUp` to get called.